# Express.js routing with optional param?

Tags: node.js, express

I have two situations to get data from DB

1. To show normal data

   ```
   http://exampleapp.com/task/{{taskId}}
   ```
2. To edit data via posting

   ```
   http://exampleapp.com/task/{{taskId}}/?state={{app.state}}
   ```

Both url have the same `http://exampleapp.com/task/{{taskId}}` just a little bit different with last phrase `?state={{app.state}}`

I use Express routing as followed:

```
app.get('/task/:taskId/(?state=:status(pending|cancel|confirmed|deleted))?', routes.task.show);
```

But I dont know why it does not work ?

For example error: Cannot GET /task/51d2c53f329b8e0000000001 when going to h**p://exampleapp.com/task/51d2c53f329b8e0000000001

Comment: Can you give a little more details on what you're seeing exactly? I assume you actually have *two* routes, one for each of the cases you need to support? Can you show both? Does one of them work?

Comment: After setting router above, when navigating to http://localhost:3000/task/51d2c53f329b8e0000000001, I got error Cannot GET /task/51d2c53f329b8e0000000001 
Because both 2 URLS are nearly the same, so I combine into 1 route

Answer (score 2):

Query strings cannot be defined in routes.  You access query string parameters from `req.query`.

```
app.get('/task/:taskId', function(req, res) {
    if (req.query.state == 'pending') { ... }
});
```

However, if you're *modifying* a task, this is not the appropriate way to do it.  `GET` requests SHOULD be idempotent: the request SHOULD NOT modify state.  That's what `POST` requests are for.

```
app.get('/task/:taskId', function(req, res) {
    // show task info based on `req.params.taskId`
});

app.post('/task/:taskId', function(req, res) {
    // set task `req.params.taskId` to state `req.body.state`
});
```

You could either have a `<form>` that posts to the task, or make an ajax request:

```
$.post('/task/1', { state: 'pending' }, function() { ... });
```

Comment: I modified my code  by using put to update after get query string from url and it works now. Anyways thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Express API](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB), you cannot mix RegExp routes with string routes.

You should do something like this (I'm assuming `taskId` is an integer):

```
app.get(/^\/task/([0-9]+)/(?state=:status(pending|cancel|confirmed|deleted))?, routes.task.show);
```

However, I don't see why you cannot only check if `req.query.state` is defined in your route. It's probably less error prone and easier:

```
app.get("/task/:taskId", function( req, res, next ) {
  if (req.query.state) {
    // Do things
  }

  next();
});
```

Comment: After modifying code by using query state and it works as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that query strings are not considered in routing. You will either have to redesign your urls (ie, include the state into the url itself, instead of the query string) or check the query string in your route handler function.